# Automatically Build GitHub Branch on Commit

Tags: github, jenkins

I am new to working with Jenkins pipeline. I am able to use the GitHub Plugin in Jenkins and Webhooks from GitHub to successfully build a specific branch of a repository for a free style job. I can't find documentation that documents how to setup the "Source Code Management" so that only specific branches are build based on the github webhook.

For now I can chain the pipeline job to a free style job so that I can build only specific branches. I would rather have the pipeline job configured specifically for the branch we are trying to build.

Thanks in advance for your help!

SCM Configuration for the pipeline job. 
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NoOX.png

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this within a Jenkins Pipeline job, you must mark the Pipeline Definition as "Pipeline script from SCM". This will instruct Jenkins to base the pipeline execution based on a Jenkinsfile within the repository. Here, you can also instruct Jenkins which branches to build.

From there, you simply need to make sure that your GitHub pushes are triggering builds within Jenkins correctly, and that's all there is to it!

Comment: Hey cstarner! Thanks for the note. I have the pipeline job configured as you described  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NoOX.png) as well as the options in build triggers  "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" and "Poll SCM"  set. When we push to any branch in the repository, the pipeline builds.

Comment: Good to hear. Did that solve your problem, or are you still running into issues?

Comment: Yes - the issue persists. I had that configuration in place prior to posting here. Any thoughts on how to continue to trouble shoot?

Comment: After rereading your comment, the issue likely stems from having both Webhooks and Polling enabled on the same Job. Both can cause jobs to begin building, and have entirely separate sets of filters in Jenkins. If pushing to any branch causes a build, I would assume the problem is coming from the polling side (especially if pushing to the intended branch causes two jobs to start at once)

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can use the fuller form of the checkout scm command, which will let you specify branches programatically if needed. You can see how to do this via `http://myjenkins.org/pipeline-syntax/`

Comment: Hey; sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I abandon the pipeline build job and went with the multi-branch pipeline build. It is more than we need, but I can filter the branches we want to auto build for.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the pipeline job was to build and deploy specific branch automatically. The approach was to create a pipeline job and define the branch in the SCM configuration and enable webhooks so that the branch would automatically build when a new commit is pushed. Unfortunately the webhook SCM build for pipeline is broken or is not supported for webhooks.

We have decided to change our approach and use the multibranch pipeline job. This by default build ALL branches that have a jenkinsFile. We are filtering in the job for the specific branches we want automatically build.